# R: reading and manipulating a strangely formatted file

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a file that is formatted in a slightly weird way, like so:

```
Cluster 1       Score:3.96  
Category        Term        Count
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006412  34
KEGG_PATHWAY    hsa00970    9
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0043038  9
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0043039  9

Cluster 2       Score:3.94  
Category        Term        Count
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006414  21
KEGG_PATHWAY    hsa03010    20
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0034660  16
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006399  11
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0042254  10
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0022613  12
```

... and several more "sub-data frames" (including space in-between) and additional (here omitted) columns for the rows after the `Cluster X` rows.

What I want to do is to somehow read each separate cluster, get it as a data frame (i.e. a data frame with the names `Category, Term, Count`), manipulate the data frame a bit (adding columns based on calculations, mostly) and then write the manipulated data frame AND the the `Cluster X` row to a new file on the very same format as it started.

I've racked my brain for some smart way to do this, but I haven't really come up with anything other than reading each row separately and doing different things depending on the type of row, like this:

```
con  <- file('test.txt', open="r")

# Read file line for line
while ( length(currentLine <- readLines(con, n=1, warn=FALSE)) > 0 ) {
  line = strsplit(currentLine, '\t')[[1]]

  # Save previous data, initiate new cluster name/score
  if ( grepl('Annotation Cluster', line[1]) ) {

    # Save previous data if available
    if ( exists('currentData') ) {
      ## save the current data somehow
    }

    # Initiate new
    clusterInfo = line
  } 
  # Initiate new, empty data frame
  else if ( grepl('Category', line[1]) ) {
    currentData = data.frame(t(rep(NA, length(line))))
    names(currentData) = line
  } 
  # Add data to data frame
  else if ( grepl('GOTERM', line[1]) || grepl('KEGG', line[1]) ) {
    currentData = rbind(currentData, line)

    # Delete NAs if line row
    if ( nrow(currentData) == 2 ) {
      currentData = na.omit(currentData)
    }
  }
}
```

The above is obviously not finished (I'm not sure how to save the `clusterInfo` together with `currentData` to the same format), but I hope I get across my idea. I'm not really too fond of this approach, though... It seems very odd, to me, to create data frames row-by-row like this, and try and save the data at the same time as you're initiating the start of the next block of data.

Is there some better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`read.mtable`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/read.mtable.R) from my GitHub-only ["SOfun" package](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun).

Usage would be something like:

```
library(SOfun)
read.mtable(x, "Cluster", header = TRUE) ## Replace "x" with your file name
# $`Cluster 1       Score:3.96`
#        Category       Term Count
# 1 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0006412    34
# 2  KEGG_PATHWAY   hsa00970     9
# 3 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0043038     9
# 4 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0043039     9
# 
# $`Cluster 2       Score:3.94`
#        Category       Term Count
# 1 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0006414    21
# 2  KEGG_PATHWAY   hsa03010    20
# 3 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0034660    16
# 4 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0006399    11
# 5 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0042254    10
# 6 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0022613    12
```

---

As you acn see, the "cluster" information is retained as the list names. Thus, you can go ahead and use `lapply` to do whatever calculations you need to do, and then re-write the data in whatever form you need to.

---

Reproducible sample data:

```
x <- tempfile()

writeLines("Cluster 1       Score:3.96  
Category        Term        Count
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006412  34
KEGG_PATHWAY    hsa00970    9
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0043038  9
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0043039  9

Cluster 2       Score:3.94  
Category        Term        Count
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006414  21
KEGG_PATHWAY    hsa03010    20
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0034660  16
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0006399  11
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0042254  10
GOTERM_BP_FAT   GO:0022613  12", con = x, sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great function! Does just what I want =D

Answer (score 1):

You could read the file with `readLines` and `split` it with a numeric index ('indx') created based on the lines having 'Cluster'.  Read the list elements with `read.table`, create two new columns ('Cluster' and 'Score') and rbind the list elements to create a single dataset.

```
lines <- readLines('Clusterfile.txt')
indx <- cumsum(grepl('^Cluster', lines))
res <-  do.call(rbind,lapply(split(lines, indx), function(x) {
        d1 <-read.table(text=x[-1], header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        d2 <- read.table(text=gsub('[^0-9.]+', ' ', x[1]), 
          col.names=c('Cluster', 'Score'))
        cbind(d1, d2)}))

row.names(res) <- NULL
head(res,3)
#       Category       Term Count Cluster Score
#1 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0006412    34       1  3.96
#2  KEGG_PATHWAY   hsa00970     9       1  3.96
#3 GOTERM_BP_FAT GO:0043038     9       1  3.96
```